# Таймер, кнопка и JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, почему цифра, которая выводится через text отстает от таймера на 1 ?

```
function dis()
{


    $("#send").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#send").css({"background-color":"#d6d6d6","border-color":"#d6d6d6"});

    var ssUnb = 5; //5 секунд обратный отсчет

        $("#h").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#send").text(ssUnb); //ВЫВОДИТ цифру 5
        countd = setInterval(function(){
     $("#send").text(ssUnb);   
        --ssUnb; // с ssUnb-- то же самое
        console.log(ssUnb); //НАЧИНАЕТ с 4 А НЕ с 5
        if(ssUnb <= 0 ){
             $("#send").attr("disabled",false);
             $("#send").css({"background-color":"#428bfa","border-color":"#428bfa"});
             $("#h").css({"display":"block"});
            clearInterval(countd);

        }
    }, 1000);


}
```

Я в принципе понимаю, почему так происходит..но не понимаю, как исправить

Comment: Расскажите, почему так происходит, как вы понимаете?

Comment: Тупанул..исправил уже )

Comment: Если нашли решение, можете написать ответ на свой вопрос.